# php email attachment

Tags: php, email

i am using [this](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4595.html) script for the email attachment but when i execute the form on my server it shows to warning

> Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
>
> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

pls help

Comment: http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4595.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$fp = fopen($strresume, "rb"); 
$file = fread($fp, $strresume_size);
```

to this:

```
$fp = fopen($filetemp, "rb"); 
$file = fread($fp, $strresume_size);
```

Comment: I would suggest echoing out each value before you test on it (`print_r($_FILES])` and seeing the data that is coming in.

Comment: okie  Chacha102 thanks for helping me if u have any script similer like this thread plz put it here

Comment: Oh! Now I know. change $strresume to $filetemp here: $fp = fopen($strresume, "rb");

Comment: I put the change needed in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use this function to send HTML email with an attachment:

http://www.barattalo.it/2010/01/10/sending-emails-with-attachment-and-html-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

The script behaves differently as per hosting config. So either use file name in all places `$strresume` or use the variable it has assign to. i.e. `$strname`, `$strtype`, `$strsize`, `$strtemp`.

Answer (score 0):

I used **[phpmailer class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/PHPMailer_v5.1.zip/download)**. Its very simple.

procedure- http://www.phpexpertsforum.com/how-to-add-doc-file-as-attachment-to-sending-mail-from-php-t649.html