# Sending attachments using mail() - not attaching

Tags: php, email

I have been working with: http://www.sitepoint.com/article/advanced-email-php/6/ along with other articles on trying to get my email to be sent with an attachment and as of now:

It sends the email, with the plain text content, it looks like: http://pastie.org/569806

My code as of now is: http://pastie.org/569803 - I didn't want to paste the code here; it's around 100 lines.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219632/php-email-attachment

Comment: Dont develop the wheel all over again. Use finished code like Zend_Mail.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using one of the many available wrappers for PHP's unwieldy mail function, such as:

- [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail)
- [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html)
- [LibMail](http://lwest.free.fr/doc/php/lib/Mail/)

...and many others, to avoid the headache of the low-level yuck, especially with regard to creating/manipulating/sending attachments.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be picking up the mail headers. I see you started the headers on line 52 with a '\n' instead of a '\r\n' - does changing that help?